# @Transactional rabbit listener cause infinite loop

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Hi I have problem with my Rabbit listener which cause infinite loop on exception (requeue message). My configuration looks:

```
@Bean(name = "defContainer")
public RabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager){
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    containerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    containerFactory.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
    containerFactory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    containerFactory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    containerFactory.setMessageConverter(messageConverterAmqp());
    containerFactory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);

    return new TxRabbitListenerContainerFactory(containerFactory);
}
```

where transactionManager is JpaTransactionManager for transaction on postgre db.
TxRabbitListenerContainerFactory is my factory which set setAlwaysRequeueWithTxManagerRollback to false:

```
public class TxRabbitListenerContainerFactory implements RabbitListenerContainerFactory {
private SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory;

public TxRabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
}

@Override
public MessageListenerContainer createListenerContainer(RabbitListenerEndpoint endpoint) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = factory.createListenerContainer(endpoint);
    container.setAlwaysRequeueWithTxManagerRollback(false);
    return container;
}
```

}

Now I have listner like:

```
@RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = "topic.two", durable = "true"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "topic.def", type = "topic", durable = "true"),
        key = "letter.*"
), errorHandler = "rabErrorHandler", containerFactory = "defContainer")
@Transactional
public Motorcycle topicLetters(Motorcycle motorcycle) throws Exception{
    motorcycle.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    Testing testing = new Testing();
    testingRepository.save(testing);
    throwEx();
    return motorcycle;
}
```

where method **throwEx();** throw unchecked exception.
Data from DB are properly rollbacked (not commited), but message are constantly requeued, see it in listener:

```
@Bean
public RabbitListenerErrorHandler rabErrorHandler(){
    return new RabbitListenerErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object handleError(Message message, org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message1, ListenerExecutionFailedException e) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFF");
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

How to prevvent infinite loope, and why is it happend ?

**EDIT:**

Logs: [pasted logs](http://pasted.co/d718335e)

Answer (score 1):

Set `defaultRequeueRejected` to `false` on the container factory.

To programmatically decide when to requeue or nor, leave that at `true` and throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` when you don't want it requeued.

**EDIT**

There's something not adding up...

```
protected void prepareHolderForRollback(RabbitResourceHolder resourceHolder, RuntimeException exception) {
    if (resourceHolder != null) {
        resourceHolder.setRequeueOnRollback(isAlwaysRequeueWithTxManagerRollback() ||
                RabbitUtils.shouldRequeue(isDefaultRequeueRejected(), exception, logger));
    }
}
```

If both booleans are false, we don't requeue.

Comment: actually I have containerFactory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false); on factory. This is reason why I don't know how it is still requeue. Also I have my modified factory which set container.setAlwaysRequeueWithTxManagerRollback(false); on every container because it need to be set because tx in this case is grabbed by jpaTransactionManager

Comment: Sorry - missed that; what version are you using? Can you attach a DEBUG log snippet that shows the loop? Also see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Found issue:
Reason: caused by errorHandler handler which was specified on listener level. In some cases error handler return null - which was causing infinite loop (instead rethrowing exception and rollback transaction)